# Is it Undefined Behavior to call virtual functions of union member with a common base class as another member?

Tags: c++, unions, type-punning

Specifically, I would like to be able to use polymorphism without heap allocation in an embedded context (thus without dynamic allocation). My concern here seems to be that accessing the `base` member while `x` or `y` are "active" in the union seems to be an instance of type-punning, even though they share the same initial header (and vtable structure). Would the code below be considered defined behavior?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
    virtual const char *foo() { return "base"; }
};

struct X: public Base {
    const char *foo() override { return "d1"; }
};

struct Y: public Base {
    const char *foo() override { return "d2"; }
};

union DerivedAny {
    DerivedAny() {}
    Base& get() { return *launder(&b); }
    Base b = {};
    X x;
    Y y;
};

DerivedAny objs[3];

int main() {
    new (&objs[1].x) X;
    new (&objs[2].y) Y;
    cout << objs[0].get().foo() << endl;
    cout << objs[1].get().foo() << endl;
    cout << objs[2].get().foo() << endl;
}
```

I've compiled it with both GCC and Clang and they to appear to return the expected output in both cases:

```
base
d1
d2
```

Comment: I am pretty sure your analysis is correct. Accessing inactive member of the union is UB

Comment: I think what you're trying to solve might be better if you implement your own polymorphism instead on relying on virtual functions

Comment: Have you considered `std::variant` and `visit`?

Comment: std::variant and std::visit doesn't seem too scalable, and std::visit, being essentially a switch statement, somewhat defeats the idea of using polymorphism in the first place.